# Why Won't Deleting vimrc Reset Vim Settings? (Mac)

Tags: vim, homebrew, vimrc, macvim

I reinstalled Macvim using Homebrew, deleted and reinstalled both the vim folder at `/usr/shared/vim` and `vimrc`.

When I open text files with vim the settings are the same and any changes I make to the new `vimrc` file have no effect. Does Macvim initialize settings from a different file? I'm running macOS Sierra 10.12.6. I'm running version 8.1 for vim. Thanks in advance!